# Java GUI: about getContentPane( ) method and content

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In this piece of code:

```
JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I can see it makes a new label and adds it to the `JFrame` object `frame`. 
But I want to understand what does `getContentPane()` do, and why do I need it?

I read [this API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane()) but I still didn't understand.

Comment: Nice story: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/hansmuller/archive/2005/11/jframeadd_conte.html

Comment: lool, that geek article xd

Comment: "As a convenience `add` and its variants…have been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary."—[`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every `JPanel` is a container, so either add it to a panel then add it to the container or directly use `add(component)` or use the `getContentPane().add` method. Both add the component to the container in Java 7 (*I don't know if version 6 has a problem with this or not*).

Comment: The [forwarding to the `contentPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) feature appeared in Java 5.

Answer (score 31):

Every Swing top level container (and JInternalFrame) has what's called a `JRootPane`.  This is responsible for actually managing the overall layout of the window.

[image]

The root pane has a number of layers, one of which is the content pane.  When you add something to a frame (since Java 5 I think), it is automatically added to the content pane for you, before this, you had to call `getContentPane().add(...)` yourself

Take a look at [How to use RootPanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Comment: +1, a nice and suitable post. Understand by newbies like me too :) thanks

Answer (score 5):

A **container** has several layers in it. You can think of a layer as a transparent film that overlays the **container**. In Java Swing, the layer that is used to hold objects is called the **content pane**. Objects are added to the content pane layer of the **container**.

The **getContentPane()** method retrieves the **content pane layer** so that you can add an object to it. The content pane is an object created by the **Java run time environment**. You do not have to know the name of the content pane to use it. When you use **`getContentPane()`**, the content pane object then is substituted there so that you can apply a method to it.

Answer (score 2):

A JFrame is the headcomponent which is put together with other subcomponents. With getContentPane() gets the component that represents the contents of a graphical user interface. A JMenuBar for example is placed in another area next to the contentPane of a frame.