# Swing - How to change the backgroundcolor of a Jframe/Jdialog

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to change the backgroundcolor of my Jframe & Jdialog.
Adjusting the 'Background' in the GUI is not working.
Any idea how I can change the background color?

Comment: Asked and answered here *many* times. In the future, please search on your problem first to see if it is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always do this using java code, by calling the contentpane of your jframe.

try this :

```
myJFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: Where exacly do I place it? Nvm I found it :) Thanks!

Comment: you need to put it in code part of your jframe, since you are using netbeans just double click on any button or menu in your jframe or right click and go to code and put this in class constructor  to initialize with jframe.

Comment: if this solved your problem , please mark it as answer

Comment: @Alok Why do we need to call `getContentPane()` first? JFrame has direct access to `setBackground()`.

Comment: @Brian if you are using content pane it will overlap jframe background, think of it as stack of elements in z-index one above another, if you dont have content pane you can change jframe background directly. we usuallly works with taking panels or content pane hence the answer

Comment: also something for your further studies on same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744152/java-gui-about-getcontentpane-method-and-content

Comment: @Alok Thanks! :-)